# how to save php session data in memory in windows?

Tags: php, windows, session, memory

That is I need to get rid of the sess* files that php is producing and I know that adverse effect of restarting server might be deletion of session data, but I can live with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the built-in (well, if you have the memcached extension installed) [Memcached Session Handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php) to store them in a session.

Alternatively, you could write your own [Session Save Handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) to store it in a database or other memory storage (such as APC, etc).

Or, you could use one of the many session implementations out there such as:

- [Zend Session](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.html)
- [Pear Session 2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Session2/redirected)
- [Code Igniter Sessions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)
- etc...

Answer (score 3):

PHP by itself stores sessions in file : this is the default.

But, you can set your own session handler, that will store data somewhere else.

Candidates generally are :

- Database -- you'll need a database server
- [memcached](http://memcached.org/) -- you'll need a memcached server.

See the [**Custom Session Handlers**][2] section of the manual, and [`session_set_save_handler()`][3] for an example.

If you choose to use memcached to store your sessions in memory, it comes with a session handler : using it is just a matter of configuration *(see `session.save_handler` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php))*